# Matching numbers by their order when in two different vectors

Tags: r, loops

The title does not really do this question justice, but I could not think of any other way to phrase the question. I can best explain the problem with an example.

Let's say we have two vectors of numbers (each of which are always going to be ascending and unique):

```
vector1 <- c(1,3,10,11,24,26,30,31)
vector2 <- c(5,9,15,19,21,23,28,35)
```

What I am trying to do is create a function that will take these two vectors and match them in the following way:

1) Start with the first element of vector1 (in this case, 1)

2) Go to vector2 and match the element from #1 with the first element in vector 2 that is bigger than it (in this case, 5)

3) Go back to vector1 and skip all elements less than the value in #2 we found (in this case, we skip 3, and grab 10)

4) Go back to vector2 and skip all elements less than the value in #3 we found (in this case, we skip 9 and grab 15)

5) repeat until we are done with all elements.

The resulting two vectors we should have are:

```
result1 = c(1,10,24,30)
result2 = c(5,15,28,35)
```

My current solution goes something like this, but I believe it might be highly inefficient:

```
# establishes where we start from the vector2 numbers
# just in case we have vector1 <- c(5,8,10)
# and vector2 <- c(1,2,3,4,6,7). We would want to skip the 1,2,3,4 values

  i <- 1
  while(vector2[i]<vector1[1]){
    i <- i+1
  }

# starts the result1 vector with the first value from the vector1

  result1 <- vector1[1]

# starts the result2 vector empty and will add as we loop through

  result2 <- c()


# super complicated and probably hugely inefficient loop within a loop within a loop 
# i really want to avoid doing this, but I cannot think of any other way to accomplish this

  for(j in 1:length(vector1)){

    while(vector1[j] > vector2[i] && (i+1) <= length(vector2)){

      result1 <- c(result1,vector1[j])
      result2 <- c(result2,vector2[i])         

      while(vector1[j] > vector2[i+1] && (i+2) <= length(vector2)){

        i <- i+1
      }
      i <- i+1
    }
  }

  ## have to add on the last vector2 value cause while loop skips it
  ## if it doesn't exist (there are no more vector2 values bigger) we put in an NA

  if(result1[length(result1)] < vector2[i]){
    result2 <- c(result2,vector2[i])
  }
  else{
    ### we ran out of vector2 values that are bigger 
    result2 <- c(result2,NA)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really difficult to explain. Just call it magic :)

```
vector1 <- c(1,3,10,11,24,26,30,31)
vector2 <- c(5,9,15,19,21,23,28,35)
## another case
# vector2 <- c(0,9,15,19,21,23,28,35)

## handling the case where vector2 min value(s) are < vector1 min value
if (any(idx <- which(min(vector1) >= vector2))) 
   vector2 <- vector2[-idx]

## interleave the two vectors
tmp <- c(vector1,vector2)[order(c(order(vector1), order(vector2)))]

## if we sort the vectors, which pairwise elements are from the same vector
r <- rle(sort(tmp) %in% vector1)$lengths

## I want to "remove" all the pairwise elements which are from the same vector
## so I again interleave two vectors:
## the first will be all TRUEs because I want the first instance of each *new* vector
## the second will be all FALSEs identifying the elements I want to throw out because
## there is a sequence of elements from the same vector
l <- rep(1, length(r))
ord <- c(l, r - 1)[order(c(order(r), order(l)))]

## create some dummy TRUE/FALSE to identify the ones I want
res <- sort(tmp)[unlist(Map(rep, c(TRUE, FALSE), ord))]

setNames(split(res, res %in% vector2), c('result1', 'result2'))

# $result1
# [1]  1 10 24 30
# 
# $result2
# [1]  5 15 28 35
```

obviously this will only work if both vectors are ascending and unique which you said

EDIT:

works with duplicates:

```
vector1 <- c(1,3,10,11,24,26,30,31)
vector2 <- c(5,9,15,19,21,23,28,35)
vector2 <- c(0,9,15,19,21,23,28,35)
vector2 <- c(1,3,3,5,7,9,28,35)

f <- function(v1, v2) {
  if (any(idx <- which(min(vector1) >= vector2))) 
    vector2 <- vector2[-idx]

  vector1 <- paste0(vector1, '.0')
  vector2 <- paste0(vector2, '.00')

  n <- function(x) as.numeric(x)

  tmp <- c(vector1, vector2)[order(n(c(vector1, vector2)))]

  m <- tmp[1]
  idx <- c(TRUE, sapply(1:(length(tmp) - 1), function(x) {
    if (n(tmp[x + 1]) > n(m)) {
      if (gsub('^.*\\.','', tmp[x + 1]) == gsub('^.*\\.','', m)) 
        FALSE
      else {
        m <<- tmp[x + 1]
        TRUE
      }
    } else FALSE
  }))

  setNames(split(n(tmp[idx]), grepl('\\.00$', tmp[idx])), c('result1','result2'))
}
f(vector1, vector2)

# $result1
# [1]  1 10 30
# 
# $result2
# [1]  3 28 35
```

Comment: that is such a clever solution. I never thought of interleaving the two vectors ( I guess I didn't make the most out of my ascending and uniqueness assumptions). 

I just changed the last line of code and got it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry to be a bother, but I noticed a bug when trying to compare it to my previous solution. If the vector1 values start ABOVE the vector2 values, the output is not correct. For example, vector1 = (3,10,...) and vector2 being (1,5,9...)

I fixed this by simply adjusting vector2 to remove any values that are below the initial value of vector1

Comment: can you just use vector2 as vector 1 and vice versa? that is, always use the vector with the smallest first element first?

Comment: yes, that should also work! Vector1 in my application of this idea in my code though has a specific meaning so I was trying to order them in a specific way. But for purposes of this question alone, that might be a better solution

Comment: Maybe adding this line would work for that situation `if (any(idx <- which(min(vector1) >= vector2))) vector2 <- vector2[-idx]` see edit

Comment: is that code to ignore vector2 values less than the min more efficient than looping through to the i-th value? I.e.,
      
    i <- 1
      while(vector2[i]<vector1[1]){
        i <- i+1
      }
      vector2 <- vector2[i:length(vector2)]

Comment: loops are not very "R" but in this case, if you had huge vectors, the while loop may be more efficient since you would only be evaluating elements up until the condition fails whereas `which`, even though it is vectorized, will evaluate the entire vector before moving onto the next task

Comment: How would you approach this problem if the numbers were only increasing but not unique? Namely vector1 and vector2 share some values

Comment: @road_to_quantdom see edits. I think this is more straight-forward and works better than the original

Comment: wouldn't we want the result1 to be c(1,3,10,30) and result2 to be c(3,5,28,35)

Comment: idk, idk your setting or how or why you want to handle duplicates. I start at the first element of the first vector and go to the second and throw away elements until I find something bigger than the one I have, and repeat. That's what the question says

Comment: yes, so we start with 1 from vector1. Go to vector2 and choose 3. Then when we go back to vector1, we grab 3 since 3 >= 3. We go to vector2 and choose 5. Then go back to vector1 and grab 10 since 10 >= 5.

Comment: that's what the gsub conditional was checking for, so take that out and you'll be fine